# How to ban and kick a GuildMember

Tags: discord.js

Well, I followed "The Source Code" "discord.js" tutorial, (even copy-pasted his code from GitHub) but the ban and kick commands he's shown don't work, I assume they got broken by a recent update. It sends the embed to the incidents channel but doesn't actually ban the player. Also, if you have any suggestions for me to change things, please suggest!

```js
if (cmd === `${prefix}ban`) {
  let bUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]));
  if (!bUser) return message.channel.send("Can't find user!");
  let bReason = args.join(" ").slice(22);
  if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("No can do pal!");
  if (bUser.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.channel.send("That person can't be banned!");

  let banEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setDescription("Ban Management")
    .setColor("#bc0000")
    .addField("Banned User", `${bUser} with ID ${bUser.id}`)
    .addField("Banned By", `<@${message.author.id}> with ID ${message.author.id}`)
    .addField("Banned In", message.channel)
    .addField("Time", message.createdAt)
    .addField("Reason", bReason);

  let incidentchannel = message.guild.channels.find(`name`, "incidents");
  if (!incidentchannel) return message.channel.send("Can't find incidents channel.");

  message.guild.member(bUser).ban(bReason);
  message.delete().catch(O_o => {});
  incidentchannel.send(banEmbed);

  return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
message.guild.member(bUser).ban(bReason);
```

This will not ban the member. The message has a `member` property so you don't need to use `message.guild.member` you can just easily use [`message.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member).

So it should look like this:

```
if (cmd === `${prefix}ban`) {
  let bUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]));
  if (!bUser) return message.channel.send("Can't find user!");
  let bReason = args.join(" ").slice(22);
  if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("No can do pal!");
  if (bUser.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.channel.send("That person can't be banned!");

  let banEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setDescription("Ban Management")
    .setColor("#bc0000")
    .addField("Banned User", `${bUser.user.tag} with ID ${bUser.id}`)
    .addField("Banned By", `<@${message.author.id}> with ID ${message.author.id}`)
    .addField("Banned In", message.channel.name)
    .addField("Time", message.createdAt)
    .addField("Reason", bReason);

  let incidentchannel = message.guild.channels.find(`name`, "incidents");
  if (!incidentchannel) return message.channel.send("Can't find incidents channel.");

  message.guild.member(bUser).ban({
    reason: bReason
  });
  message.delete();
  incidentchannel.send({
    embed: banEmbed
  });

  return;
}
```

I changed a lot because a lot was outdated and could not work. It could be that I haven't seen one or the other mistake.

Let me know if it worked! :)

Best regards,
Monkeyyy11

Answer (score 0):

If you use `discord.js` v12 or higher, then `RichEmbed` is now deprecated. Instead, use [`MessageEmbed`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed)

Answer (score 0):

This seems awfully complicated, I hope my command can make things a bit easier!

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    const arguments = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const commandName = arguments.shift().toLowerCase();
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix) && commandName == "kick") {
    if(!message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("Permissions invalid");
    const userKick = message.mentions.users.first();

    if (userKick) {
        var member = message.guild.member(userKick);

        if (member) {
            member.kick({
                reason: `This person was kicked using a bot's moderation system. We are so sorry if this caused problems.`
    }).then(() => {
        message.reply(`A user been kicked.`) 
    })
} else {
    message.reply(`User not found`);
}
    } else {
        message.reply(`Please enter a name`)
    }}})


    bot.on('message', message => {
        const arguments = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
        const commandName = arguments.shift().toLowerCase();
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix) && commandName == "ban") {
        if(!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("Permissions invalid");
        const userBan = message.mentions.users.first();
    
        if (userBan) {
            var member = message.guild.member(userBan);
    
            if (member) {
                member.ban({
                    reason: `This person was banned using a bot's moderation system. We are so sorry if this caused problems.`
        }).then(() => {
            message.reply(`a user has been banned!`) 
        })
    } else {
        message.reply(`User not found`);
    }
        } else {
            message.reply(`Please enter a name`)
        }}})
```